# The class starts at noon. vs Class starts at noon

Tags: definite-article

I am going to write down two similar sentences below.

(1) The class starts at noon.

(2) Class starts at noon.

This is my interpretation. You say (1) when you are talking about when a specific course starts. In contrast, you say (2) when you are talking about when all courses generally start. Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have interpreted #1 correctly. If someone says, "The class starts at noon," then we are talking about a specific class, and both the speaker and listener know which class is being talked about.

As for interpretation #2, I don't think that's accurate. If I wanted to talk about "when all courses generally start," then I would use the plural form:

> Classes start at noon.

As for the meaning of "Class starts at noon," that's tricky to explain. It pretty much means the same thing as the first sentence. When talking about the start time of an event, we can often omit the article all together and the resulting sentence sounds natural, understandable, and idiomatic. For example:

> Class starts at noon.
>   Lunch starts at 11:30.
>   School starts at 8 o'clock.
>   Doors open at seven.
>   Court begins at 9 o'clock sharp.

Sometimes that same structure is understandable and acceptable, but it sounds more "clipped" and informal:

> Wedding starts at two o'clock; reception begins at three-thirty.
>   Train leaves at noon. Bus leaves at one.

I would understand those sentences – especially in a context like a brief email – but I think that determiners might make the sentences sound a bit more smooth:

> The wedding starts at two o'clock; our reception begins at three-thirty.
>   The train leaves at noon and the bus leaves at one.